# Redirecting Bluehost subdomain to a Plesk subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, plesk, bluehost, mediatemple

My client has their domain names and servers spread across Media Temple and Bluehost - so I'm not sure the best way to approach this. They have a domain name registered on Bluehost, but I need to point it towards a subdirectory on Plesk. I have limited networking experience - I'm not sure how to access the IP address or the subdirectory that has the subdomains files installed.

For example, on Bluehost I have dev.example.com registered and I have a WordPress install on Plesk at /httpdocs/dev of my parent domain and I need to point dev.example.com to **parent**/httpdocs/dev.

Answer (score 0):

The right and simplest way is to create new domain dev.example.com inside of your subscription and point "Document root" to httpdocs/dev

!! important note here !!

Test it on some other non empty test folder because the content of folder may be **deleted!**